# Sql server combine multiple data sets without duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

Given three tables Ta, Tb, Tc:

```
Ta(ID, Field1)
Tb(ID, Field2)
Tc(ID, Field3)
```

Given data example:

```
Ta
ID Field1
---------
1  A
1  B

Tb
ID Field2
---------
1  C
1  D
2  E

Tc
ID Field3
---------
1  F
2  G
2  H
```

**Question:**
How can I join this data to return:

```
ID Field1 Field2 Field3
-----------------------
1  A      C      F
1  B      D      NULL
2  NULL   E      G
2  NULL   NULL   H
```

I thought I could achieve this with outer joins but that doesn't seem to be the case. The order of the groupings doesn't really matter, as long as I bring back all information without duplicate rows.

**Just to clarify.** I don't really mind which combination I get as long as the result set returns all data in the minimum number of rows. Here's a more realistic example of what I am trying to do:

Given a person, call him John. He has two phone numbers and three email addresses:

```
PID  Email
---------
John john@test.com
John john@mail.com
John john@john.com

PID  Tel
--------
John 011
John 022
```

I want to return:

```
PID  Email         Tel
----------------------
John john@test.com 011
John john@mail.com 022
John john@john.com NULL
```

Comment: Why is the last row assigned to ID = 3?

Comment: How about `1  A  D F`? And `1 B C F`? Why not return those, they're obviously missing from your return, aren't they? Before you respond, stop and think, and perhaps you'll realize the real problem with your requirement...

Comment: Your combination seems to depend on the ordering of the rows in the original tables.  In SQL (and SQL Server), the order of rows in a table is unspecified.  Do you have a row number or identity column or date or something for determining the ordering?

Comment: @Lamak My apologies. It should be two (updated). My fingers must be set to auto increment!

Comment: Your data looks completely wrong. There is no way to do what you want to do, with the columns given. You would need to depend on ordering which is not guarenteed in SQL Server.

Comment: @RemusRusanu. It doesn't matter what the combinations are as long as they all come back, so I don't care if I get `2 NULL E H and 2 NULL NULL G` or `2 NULL E G and 2 NULL NULL H`.

Comment: Does it need to be 3 columns?

Comment: "I don't care if I get `2 NULL E H` and `2 NULL NULL G` or 2 `NULL E G` and `2 NULL NULL H`".  I think I need more coffee, because I'm completely baffled by this requirement.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables. It's a data extract. I simply need to see the associated data in as little rows as possible. It doesn't matter how they are ordered. Apart from ID, they are unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can come close with the following:

```
select coalesce(ta.id, tb.id, tc.id), ta.field1, tb.field2, tc.field3
from (select ta.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from ta
     ) ta full outer join
     (select tb.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from tb
     ) tb
     on ta.id = tb.id and
        ta.seqnum = tb.seqnum
     (select tc.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from tc
     ) tc
     on coalesce(ta.id, tb.id) = tc.id and
        coalesce(ta.seqnum, tb.seqnum) = tc.seqnum
group by coalesce(ta.id, tb.id, tc.id),
         coalesce(ta.seqnum, tb.seqnum, tc.seqnum)
order by 1, 2
```

As I said, though, in my comment, the ordering of rows in a table is not guaranteed, so these may not come out in the order you expect.  With your sample data, you could use:

```
over (partition by id order by field<n>)
```

If the fields define the ordering

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative, using CTE's and a Union, with [MIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) to exclude the nulls. It doesn't guarantee the ordering, but as since you say you don't care as long as the ID's are all present.

SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dad5/8)

```
WITH TaRanked AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Field1) as Rnk, ID, Field1
  FROM Ta
),
TbRanked AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Field2) as Rnk, ID, Field2
  FROM Tb
),
TcRanked AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Field3) as Rnk, ID, Field3
  FROM Tc
),
TUnion AS
(
    SELECT Rnk, ID, Field1, NULL AS Field2, NULL AS Field3 
        FROM TaRanked 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Rnk, ID, NULL, Field2, NULL 
        FROM TbRanked 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Rnk, ID, NULL, NULL, Field3 
        FROM TcRanked 
)
SELECT ID, MIN(Field1), MIN(Field2), MIN(Field3)
  FROM TUnion
  GROUP BY ID, Rnk
  ORDER BY ID, Rnk
```

The result is

```
1   A       C       F
1   B       D       (null)
2   (null)  E       G
2   (null)  (null)  H
```

Comment: I didn't get chance to try this as Gordon Linoff's answer worked for me. That said, this appears to do the same thing but in a far more readable manner (+1). I'll let the voters take it from here! :)

Comment: Gordon is correct - the partition is needed to guarantee the minimum rows. This also then sets the desired ordering. I've updated.